# Windows System Tray Application

Tags: wpf, system-tray

I created a WPF window with system tray icon via `NotifyIcon`. When I click the icon in the system tray, the WPF application pops up and is shown on the screen.

But this solution does not fit my needs. I want the solution to be opened the same way the volumn, network center, security center, etc. is opened on system tray icon single click (just a little tiny box on top of the taskbar which can neither be moved nor has a close button in the upper right corner).

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Does `WindowStyle.None` fit your needs (Can be set in the WindowStyle Property of your Window)?

Comment: Not really because the border is also hidden.

Comment: You can easily draw your own border with WPF. Unless you want the cool transparency effect... (possible, using the AllowsTransparency Property of Windows, but probably some effort to get it look authentic)